# Как перевести фокус на окно с файлами phpstorm/webstorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains

При нахождении фокуса в рабочей области (редактор кода), каким сочетанием клавиш можно перевести его в область для выбора файлов (файловое дерево) ?

Comment: +1 к вопросу. И обратно как?

Answer (score 2):

Для открытия дерева файлов: `Alt+1`

Обратно: `Esc`

Выбрать текущий файл в дереве: `Alt+F1` затем `1`

А вообще всё можно посмотреть и настроить под себя в настройках

Comment: Это быстрее, чем комбинация в моём ответе, плюсую. Зато по Alt+F1 куча полезных вариантов вылезает.

Answer (score 0):

Можете посмотреть **[здесь](http://www.rustorm.ru/phpstorm/osnovy-raboty-s-phpstorm/znakomstvo-s-redaktorom-phpstorm/kak-polzovatsja-spravochnikom/upravlenie-vkladkami-redaktora/navigacija-mezhdu-vkladkami-redaktora-na.html)**. Я думаю там Вы найдете ответ.

**UPD:** Еще нашел такое решение

```
идете в preferences -> keymap
-> в фильтре набираете splitter
-> задаете хоткеи для Goto Next Splitter и Goto Previous Splitter
-> кайфуете
```

**UPD.2:** Еще есть такой [вариант](http://onedev.net/post/25)

Answer (score 0):

Переход в файловое дерево - Alt+F1, Enter. Назад - Esc.

Официальная документация https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf